# Enable CORS for static resources in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

I've found plenty of resources regarding CORS in Web APIs and for general controllers in ASP .NET MVC.

However, I'm in a situation where I'd like all static resources (CSS and JS files) inside a specific folder to be downloadable through AJAX as well. In other words, enable CORS for those resources or that folder.

How can I accomplish this? I've found no similar question. They are all related to web APIs or general controllers.

Comment: Does setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for that folder via IIS work? What is the reason for them to be readable via an AJAX request (just wondering as it sounds unusual)?

Comment: It probably does - if so, how can I set that header for that exact folder? Also, if possible, I'd like it to not depend on IIS, but on code. But if there's no other way, then please do share how to do this.

Comment: I would imagine that a [HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zec9k340(v=vs.85).aspx) would work. This can intercept HTTP requests and append the headers (so you can set it to only apply to requests from your particular folder).

Comment: Can you post an example of a simple module that would solve the issue? I will mark it as an answer then.

Comment: Can I ask the reason for enabling CORS for static resources?

Comment: I am working on a system where a customer needs an embed code (in other words, a JavaScript file that is located on my server). It will be embedded on to his page, but it also (through AJAX) downloads some CSS and some other JavaScript files from my server, that it then includes.

Comment: For aspnetcore : Please see my reply... static files can be protected with same CORS policy https://stackoverflow.com/a/55538788/3568316

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example adapted from [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This should add the header to all `.js` and `.css` requests.

### Create Module

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public HelloWorldModule()
    {
    }

    public String ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    // In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
    // events by adding your handlers.
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, 
         EventArgs e)
    {
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        string filePath = context.Request.FilePath;
        string fileExtension = 
            VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath);
        if (fileExtension.Equals(".css") || fileExtension.Equals(".js"))
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

### To register the module for IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 running in Classic mode

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
     </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

### To register the module for IIS 7.0 running in Integrated mode

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HelloWorldModule" type="HelloWorldModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As you are running MVC, make sure you alter the one in the root (not the `Views` folder).

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the `ModuleName` property for? It's not part of the interface you're implementing.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen i think it matches in the web.config