# MVC web api: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I tried everything that is written in this article: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api, but nothing works.
I'm trying to get data from webAPI2 (MVC5) to use in another domain using angularJS.

my controller looks like this:

```
namespace tapuzWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://local.tapuz.co.il", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
    [RoutePrefix("api/homepage")]
    public class HomePageController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetMainItems")]
        //[ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
        public List<usp_MobileSelectTopSecondaryItemsByCategoryResult> GetMainItems()
        {


            HomePageDALcs dal = new HomePageDALcs();
            //Three product added to display the data

            //HomePagePromotedItems.Value.Add(new HomePagePromotedItem.Value.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.ID == id));


            List<usp_MobileSelectTopSecondaryItemsByCategoryResult> items = dal.MobileSelectTopSecondaryItemsByCategory(3, 5);
            return items;

        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Also share your angular code for requesting cors

Comment: There is probably no problem with his angular code since most of the CORS problams are only because of the server config

Comment: I have the same kind of setup, I noticed that when I request a non-existing action on the API, and WebApi is returning a 404, the CORS header is missing and the browser will complain. So, maybe it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 331):

You need to enable **CORS** in your **Web Api**. The easier and preferred way to enable CORS globally is to add the following into **web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Please note that the *Methods* are all individually specified, instead of using `*`. This is because there is a bug occurring when using `*`.

You can also enable *CORS* by code.

**Update**
The following *NuGet* package is required: `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `[EnableCors]` attribute on Actions or Controllers like this

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Or you can register it globally

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://www.example.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // ...
    }
}
```

You also need to handle the preflight `Options` *requests* with `HTTP OPTIONS` requests.

`Web API` needs to respond to the `Options` request in order to confirm that it is indeed configured to support `CORS`.

To handle this, all you need to do is send an *empty response* back. You can do this inside your actions, or you can do it globally like this:

```
# Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

This extra check was added to ensure that old `APIs` that were designed to accept only `GET` and `POST` requests will not be exploited. Imagine sending a `DELETE` request to an `API` designed when this *verb* didn't exist. The outcome is *unpredictable* and the results might be *dangerous*.

Comment: Your answer helped me. I had tried everything I could with the code base solutions. I didn't try the web.config option until I read your answer. It was the only one that worked. Any idea why? I am using Web API 2 with OData. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Thanks. Where does this code go? I'm in web api 2 and I don't have an `Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: It goes into `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: What if the page is supposed to be https? Would this still work or some tweaking required?

Comment: CORS should not care about SSL.

Comment: Not finding the `EnableCors` or `EnableCorsAttribute` classes in any of my loaded assemblies -- what reference / NuGet package do I need to add to my project to make this work?

Comment: For future reference, the NuGet package you need for this is "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors".

Comment: so so so much appreciated for this answer, easily got my answer and solution :)

Comment: I have followed all your answer and I have two questions: Where should Application_BeginRequest() be invoked? and second, in the same method, the .Contains("Origin") doesn't really compiles at me, where is this method from, String.Contains, or from Linq.Contains?

Comment: This was very helpful. One benefit to using code is that you can open up select API methods instead of enabling access to your entire library.

Comment: This is working for webapi aax calls, but not for static html files.In this case, the OPTIONS request headers look exactly the same, but for some reason the response has an Http Status Code of 405, not 200. Do you have a solution that works for this too?

Comment: It looks like your MVC handler doesn't deal with static files. You might need to configure a separate handler for those files. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672541/enable-cors-for-static-resources-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: remember a different port # constitutes a different domain , which can be a gotcha .   foo.com _is different domain_ than foo.com:8080

Comment: the web.config entries worked for me.  I also removed the <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /> from the same section I placed the other options.  Thanks!!

Comment: The Web.config entries were also all I needed.  The WebAPI invokes that were failing with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" immediately started working for me after putting in the <httpProtocol><customHeaders> entries specified above.

Comment: The web.config update solution mentioned here did not work in my case.

Comment: Previously using `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`on each of my controller, the `accept` header was missing in Access-Control-Allow-Headers. I switched to registering globally (`EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); config.EnableCors(cors);`) and it works fine now.

Comment: I would add the following official documentation from Microsoft regarding CORS. It helped with my problem, had to add all the required handlers in the webserver section of the web.config:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 31):

@Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu's answer is correct, but for the benefit of searchers, there is also a subtle point that can cause this error.

Adding a '/' on the end of your URL will stop EnableCors from working in all instances (e.g. from the homepage).

I.e. This will not work

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://testing.azurewebsites.net/", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

but this will work:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://testing.azurewebsites.net", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The effect is the same if using the EnableCors Attribute.

Comment: Thanks!! It was helpful.

Answer (score 29):

I followed all the steps above indicated by **Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu**.
But in my case, I needed **1 more** step because http OPTIONS was disabled in the Web.Config by the line below.

`<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />`

I just removed it from Web.Config (just comment it like below) and Cors works like a charm

```
<handlers>
  <!-- remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" / -->
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 10):

It may be because of the installation of Cors nuget packages.

If you facing the problem after installing and enabaling cors from nuget , then you may try reinstalling web Api.

From the package manager, run `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall`

Comment: This was exactly it for me. I installed System.Web.Http.Cors and then uninstalled, which left WebApi on the wrong (newly upgraded) version between 5.2.2 and 5.2.3

Comment: Glad I saw this when I was setting up cors initially.  Later on, I uninstalled a package that had nothing to do with cors and it left WebAPI cors in a bad state.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, to make sure you configured CORS correctly:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Still not working? Check HTTP headers presence.

Comment: to check if its working, its better to remove supportCredentials as well, it does disable cors in certain conditions

Comment: Best answer because I don't want to enable CORS for my whole site, just certain endpoints. `config.EnableCors()` is needed for this as well.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm coming to this very late.  However, for anyone who's searching, I thought I'd publish what FINALLY worked for me.  I'm not claiming it's the best solution - only that it worked.

Our WebApi service uses the config.EnableCors(corsAttribute) method.  However, even with that, it would still fail on the pre-flight requests.  @Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu's answer provided the clue for me.  First of all, I added his Application_BeginRequest() code to flush the options requests.  That STILL didn't work for me.  The issue is that WebAPI still wasn't adding any of the expected headers to the OPTIONS request.  Flushing it alone didn't work - but it gave me an idea.  I added the custom headers that would otherwise be added via the web.config to the response for the OPTIONS request.  Here's my code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
  if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:44343");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    Response.Flush();
  }
}
```

Obviously, this only applies to the OPTIONS requests.  All other verbs are handled by the CORS configuration.  If there's a better approach to this, I'm all ears.  It feels like a cheat to me and I would prefer if the headers were added automatically, but this is what finally worked and allowed me to move on.

Comment: You are late but this helped me solve a legacy issue by adding these as http headers in the web config. Thanks

Comment: I am getting below error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://portaluat.mab.in/mabi/api/Authentication/' from origin 'https://portaluat.mab.in:8443' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 4):

To make any CORS protocol to work, you need to have a OPTIONS method on every endpoint (or a global filter with this method) that will return those headers :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
```

The reason is that the browser will send first an OPTIONS request to 'test' your server and see the authorizations

Answer (score 4):

That problem happens when you try to access from a different domain or different port.

If you're using Visual Studio, then go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. There you have to install the NuGet Package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then, in PROJECT > App_Start > WebApiConfig, enable CORS

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        
        //Enable CORS. Note that the domain doesn't have / in the end.
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("https://tiagoperes.eu",headers:"*",methods:"*"));

        ....

    }
}
```

Once installed successfully, build the solution and that should suffice

Answer (score 3):

I catch the next case about cors. Maybe it will be useful to somebody.
If you add feature 'WebDav Redirector' to your server, PUT and DELETE requests are failed.

So, you will need to remove 'WebDAVModule' from your IIS server:

- "In the IIS modules Configuration, loop up the WebDAVModule, if your web server has it, then remove it".

Or add to your config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  ...
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu's answer worked for me, e.g.:

- Adding a `<httpProtocol>`in the web.config's `<system.webServer>` section
- Returning empty response for `OPTIONS` requests via the mentioned `Application_BeginRequest()` in `global.asax`

Except that his check for `Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin")` did NOT work for me, because the request contained an `origing`, so with lowercase. I think my browser (Chrome) sends it like this for CORS requests.

I solved this a bit more generically by using [a case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) variant of his `Contains` check instead:

`if (culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(string.Join(",", Request.Headers.AllKeys), "Origin", CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

I had tried everything I could find on the net including the methods that have been given on this answer.
After almost trying to solve the problem for whole day I have found the solution that have worked for me like a charm.

in the file **WebApiConfig** in folder **App_Start**, comment all the lines of code and add the following code:

```
`public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();
        var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                                           "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                           "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Formatters.Add(new BrowserJsonFormatter());
    }

    public class BrowserJsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public BrowserJsonFormatter()
        {
            this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            this.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        }

        public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
            headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that people will probably find this very obvious at first, but really think about this.  This can often happen if you've done something wrong.

For instance, I've had this problem because I didn't add a host entry to my hosts file.  The real problem was DNS resolution.  Or I just got the base URL wrong.

Sometimes I get this error if the identity token came from one server, but I'm trying to use it on another.

Sometimes you'll get this error if you've got the resource wrong.

You might get this if you put the CORS middleware too late in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid multiple place enabling CORS,Like WebApiCOnfig.cs, GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method in provider and Controller Header attribute etc.
Below are the list which also cause the Access Control Allow Origin

1. Web having truble in interacting with DB which you used.
2. AWS Cloud If VPC of Web API and DB are different.

Below code is more then enough to fix the access control allow origin. 
//Make sure app.UseCors should be top of the code line of configuration.

```
   public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            //All other configurations
        }
    }
```

This slowed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install package : Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

go to : App_Start --> WebApiConfig

Add :

var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);

Note : If you add '/' as end of the particular url not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds crazy but for me it was [HttpPost()] instead of [HttpPost]. When I removed the redundant parentheses, it started working

Answer (score 0):

**One more scenario why CORS might not be working:** requesting non existing route.

It happened for me because route url was changed.

In such scenario preflight OPTIONS response doesn't include any CORS headers. Therefore CORS error happens and no GET-request is actually being sent, and you can't see the that actually it is 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

If you have security\requestFiltering nodes in your web.config as follows:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
      <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
      <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
      <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
      <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
      <add verb="DEBUG" allowed="true" />          
    </verbs>
  </requestFiltering>
```

make sure you add this as well

```
<add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

For people that are simply creating a Web API in .NET 5 and not a Web App, in `Startup.cs` you'll need to configure your policy like so:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Additional configs above...
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
        {
            // Allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
        });
    });
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Add this above other config options...
    app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
}
```

Comment: Won't `.AllowAnyOrigin()` leed to cross-site request forgery?